# Roslaunch files from binaries and from source

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch file that is written in my catkin_ws that includes other launch files from binaries (/opt/ros/indigo/ etc.) and from source (/catkin_ws/src/ etc.).  In order to run the launch file, I have to source the catkin_ws but if I do this, the nodes from the binary launch file cannot be found.  If I source the /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash, then the launch file can't be found because it is located in the catkin_ws.  Do I have to install all packages from source in order to accomplish this?

EDIT:

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>

   <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/minimal.launch" />

   <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/gmapping_demo.launch" />

   <include file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/global_map.launch" />

   <node name="send_exploration_goal" pkg="turtlebot_demos" type="send_exploration_goal"/>
       <param name="set_linear_vel" value="0.1" />
       <param name="set_angular_vel" value="0.1" />
   </node>

</launch>
```

The "send_exploration_goal" is a node I created and is located in my catkin_ws.  Frontier_exploration is a package I installed using apt-get and is the launch file that fails to launch.  The error message states that the two nodes that the launch file is supposed to run cannot be found in the package.  The documentation can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration).

minimal.launch and gmapping_demo.launch work without any errors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230345/roslaunch-files-from-binaries-and-from-source/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to source both. If something isn't defined in the workspace then it will be found the binary install.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-28**:
How do I source both? If I source the workspace, then the binary doesnt work but if I source the binary, the workspace doesnt work.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-03-28**:
In the standard ubuntu install for ROS it suggests you add the sourcing of the binary install to your .bashrc file, echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

If you do then the binary install is sourced in each shell you open.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-03-28**:
Then when you source the workspace it means it will be searched for files before searching the binary install location.

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-28**:
I already have that line in my ~/.bashrc.  What's weird is that other binary launch files work such as turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch and turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.  I think something is wrong with the binaries so I'm just going to reinstall from source into my catkin_ws

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-03-28**:
would need more specific details about package names, launch files and their contents - are all the things you are trying to get to work in the same name package, but some in your workspace, and some in /opt/ros ?

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-28**:
I updated the original question with specific details on the launch file I'm running. I have different packages, some from workspace and some from /opt/ros/, but one package cannot be run.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-03-28**:
can you add the actual error message as I am still unclear which nodes cannot be located

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-28**:
I don't have access to my robot right now but the error message is something like "can't locate node [explore_client] in package [frontier_exploration]" and "can't locate node [explore_server] in package [frontier_exploration]."

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-28**:
[Here's](https://github.com/paulbovbel/frontier_exploration/tree/indigo-devel/src) the github page for the node scripts.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-03-29**:
It looks like someone else has had this issue as well https://github.com/paulbovbel/frontier_exploration/issues/17

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-29**:
Yeah, I ended up reinstalling from source.  For anyone reading this who had the same problem with this package, if you install from source, you will not get all of the required header files for some reason.  My solution was to copy the header files from the binaries and add them to the source